# Update a multidimentional array from key of other

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a result array like this:

```
$result = Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => some value
            [1] => some value
            [2] => some value
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => some value
            [1] => some value
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => some value
                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => some value
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

and I have a second array

```
$test = Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
           [6] => Array
               (
                  [8] => Array
                      (
                         [0] = value to add
                      )
                )
        )
)
```

How can I update the `$result` array on base of keys from `$test` array without losing any key index.
The main point is `$result` can have any structure and is dynamically generated but the `$test` array will always have keys index(s) which will somewhat match the `$result` array. 
The general PHP array combine merge and other functions don't provide desired results.

[Edit]
The point is my second array $test will decide the position of $result where the data will be added/merged.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

By add do you mean append or addition(sum)??
This should work for appending the data.

Comment: Thank you to reply but it merges the array at the bottom and does not resolves my problem.
In my above case i need to add/merge value present at $test[4][6][8][0] to $result[4][6][8][1]
You can notice there is already a value present at $result[4][6][8][0] so i need to add another value at same depth without replacing the current one